# How do I get all values in a JIRA multi-checkbox customfield with SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, jira

I'm developing a web application that uses SOAP to communicate with JIRA. I have a custom field that contains several checkboxes, and I can get this field through SOAP, but I can't get to the actual checkboxes it contains. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I tried getting them through getCustomFields(), but they're not stored that way. The only thing I could find there was the custom field containing them, which didn't have any methods that were helpful in finding the values I needed. I know what their IDs are and I've been able to _set_ a custom field of this type when creating an issue but I haven't found any method yet that lets me _get_ them.

Comment: I have not worked with SOAP directly through JIRA, however, I've done many AJAX/JavaScript modifications against JIRA and each time I had to fall back on JQL, you can't just do a simple JQL query through SOAP?

Comment: As far as I can see, JQL can only be used to find issues (method returns RemoteIssue[])

Comment: Are you trying to get the values of the text boxes or the labels? Or both?

Comment: @Slyder, Are you required to use SOAP for this? Using a simple `GET` request and XML generated by a JQL can do this very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has answered this so far, here is an old copy of some JavaScript I did for JIRA, reading customfields.

```
var unitlist_val = $("#unitList_0").val();
var errorlist_val = $("#errorList_0").val();
var larmlist_val = $("#larmList_0").val();

var URL= ""+jira+"/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml jqlQuery=project+%3D+"+problem+
         "+AND+%22Symptom+1+-+Component%22+~+%22+"+unitlist_val+"%22+AND+%22Symptom+2+-+State%22+~+%22"+errorlist_val+
         "%22+AND+%22Symptom+3+-+alarm%22+~+%22"+larmlist_val+
         "%22&tempMax=1000&field=title&field=link&field=customfield_10422&field=customfield_10423&field=customfield_10424&field=customfield_10420&field=resolution&field=customfield_10440";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URL,
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $(data).find("item").each(function(){
                // Make sure swedish chars, are handled properly. Append to page first, then get value.
                var unitList = $("<div/>").html($(this).find("#customfield_10422 customfieldvalue").text()).text().split(",");
                var errorList = $("<div/>").html($(this).find("#customfield_10423 customfieldvalue").text()).text().split(",");
                var alarmList = $("<div/>").html($(this).find("#customfield_10424 customfieldvalue").text()).text().split(",");
                var knownerror = $("<div/>").html($(this).find("#customfield_10420 customfieldvalue").text()).text() || "None";
                var resolution = $("<div/>").html($(this).find("resolution").text()).text() || "None";
       }
    });
```

You can probably do something similar in Java and use a simple GET request. I cut out quite a lot of code, so some parts might be syntax error on.

Comment: This looks like it could work, because I can enter the URL in a browser and it shows the xml format of the things I want, but when I try to do the same through Java with URLConnection, it doesn't return any <item> nodes. Any ideas?

Comment: @Slyder, I suspect it's an authentication issue. Look at this page and view how they have specified the username and password in the url - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Automating+JIRA+operations+via+wget

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Having worked with JIRA and modifying it -  I know what hassle it can be.